# Pass Args to PyQt Worker Thread on Thread Start

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt

I'm trying to learn Python and PyQt and, while it's mostly going great, I'm having a HUGE issue with PyQt threading.  I've gotten this to work nicely using the Python "threading" module, though I get Seg Fault errors (with no additional info) on occassion.

I want to learn how to properly do threading with PyQt.  I've read "Your doing it wrong", "You weren't doing it so wrong", Maya Posch's post, the (lame) PyQt4 and (slightly less lame) PyQt5 documentation, and tons of tutorials and examples on how to do it (including lots from Stack-O) and I've only gotten more and more confused.

I've been able to get threads to start a Worker and do its thing and return data.  I can exit, emit, etc., with no problems, but I can't pass any args into the Worker.  I'm a fairly intelligent guy, but this makes me feel like a complete idiot!  Each time I read something new and try it, I feel like I'm trying to force a square peg into a round hole.

I am using the "moveToThread" feature and not sub-classing the Thread, which, according to most posts I've read, is the correct way to do it (though most examples show it as sub-classed).

If you can help me with this then I'll need more than "just send it when you do blah" - I'll need a real example or something explicit.  I HAVE seen someone come close to answering this question, but they were incredibly vague and Stack-O requires that I have 22 more reputation points in order for me to comment or ask a question on someone else's post ... ~ sigh

I have a stub script that mimics my larger script.  Here is the relevant code from the stub:

```
def pre_Flight_Check():
    #count = 0 # I want to pass THIS to the Worker at Worker's start
    fire_Up_Thread(count)
#=====================
def butStop_click():
    # Stop Loop/Thread:
    flagQuit = flagQuit + 1
#=====================
# Worker:
class Worker(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    intCount = pyqtSignal(int)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def looper(self):
        flagQuit = 0
        count = 0 # I'd like to pass this into the Worker, not define it here
        while (count < 5):
            self.intCount.emit(count)
            time.sleep(1)
            count = count + 1
            if flagQuit != 0:
                break        
        self.finished.emit()
#========================
objWorker = Worker()
thrWorker = QThread()
#========================
# Threading stuffs:
def fire_Up_Thread(count):
    # NOTE: I CAN pass the "count" var into here, just not to the Worker
    objWorker.moveToThread(thrWorker)
    thrWorker.started.connect(objWorker.looper)
    objWorker.intCount.connect(updateTextBox)
    objWorker.finished.connect(thrWorker.quit)
    objWorker.finished.connect(work_finished)        
    # Start the thread:
    thrWorker.start()
```

FYI: This is the implementation using Python Threads - it's very simple and straight-forward:

```
# Loop
def looper(count):
    flagQuit = 0

    while (count < 5):
        print(count)
        txtBox1.setText(str(count))
        time.sleep(1)
        count = count + 1
        # User clicked "Stop" button
        if flagQuit != 0:
            break
    work_finished()
#========================
def pre_Flight_Check():
    # Var(s) to send to thread:
    count = 0
    # Start Loop/Thread
    loopTest = threading.Thread(target=looper, args=(count,))
    loopTest.setDaemon(True)
    loopTest.start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using "partial" from the "functools" module allows a variable to be seen as a callable, which can then be used to pass the args on to the Worker.  Here's the original line:

```
thrWorker.started.connect(objWorker.looper)
```

and the modified line:

```
thrWorker.started.connect(partial(objWorker.looper,count,strIs))
```

And now for the entire stub re-written to incorporate the change:

```
def pre_Flight_Check():
    count = 0
    strIs = "is: " # NOTE: this is only here to show that more than 1 variable can be included
    fire_Up_Thread(count,strIs) # 2 vars to pass
#=====================
def butStop_click():
    flagQuit = flagQuit + 1
#=====================
# Worker:
class Worker(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    intCount = pyqtSignal(int)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def looper(self,count,strIs): # Both vars - "count" and "strIs"
        flagQuit = 0
        while (count < 5):
            strCount = "The count " + strIs + str(count)
            self.intCount.emit(count)
            time.sleep(1)
            count = count + 1
            # User clicked "Stop" button
            if flagQuit != 0:
                break
        self.finished.emit()
#========================
objWorker = Worker()
thrWorker = QThread()
#========================
# Threading stuffs:
def fire_Up_Thread(count,strIs): # Passed in from "pre_Flight_Check"
    from functools import partial
    objWorker.moveToThread(thrWorker)
    thrWorker.started.connect(partial(objWorker.looper,count,strIs)) # All vars are appended to connected target
    objWorker.intCount.connect(updateTextBox)
    objWorker.finished.connect(thrWorker.quit)
    objWorker.finished.connect(work_finished)
    # Start the thread:
    thrWorker.start()
```

This works, it's thread-safe, it's quick and costs very little in terms of processing.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the arguments when you initialise the `Worker`

```
class Worker(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    intCount = pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, count):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self.count = count

    @pyqtSlot()
    def looper(self):
        flagQuit = 0
        while (self.count < 5):
            self.intCount.emit(self.count)
            time.sleep(1)
            self.count = self.count + 1
            if flagQuit != 0:
                break        
        self.finished.emit()


count = 0
objWorker = Worker(count)
```

Comment: Your example still requires me to define "count" inside the Worker class under looper(self): with "self.count = 0". All my args are defined before that point, I simply need to pass them to the Worker. I didn't have an issue on my own when I defined my args in the Worker. The args are making their way to the Thread stuff, just not past it. So, to recap, I need to be able to pass already-defined args either from my pre_Flight_Check function OR from the Thread stuff to the Worker.

Comment: Sorry I left that in there by mistake when copy-pasting your example. I've updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response! I'm now getting the following errors: when I DON'T define "count" before "objWorker = Worker(count)" I get "'count' is not defined"; when I DO define it before I get "RuntimeError: super-class __init__() of type Worker was never called".

Comment: You need to define count before passing it, obviously. The `RunTimeError` is because I forgot a call to `super()` in the constructor.

Comment: In case I was a bit unclear, all my variables are defined and sanity-checked in "pre_Flight_Check"; I'm able to pass them as args into the Thread stuff (fire_Up_Thread). I need to then pass them into the Worker from either the "pre-Flight_Check" or "fire_Up_Thread".